# Need help with woocommerce roles

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles

i need help with woocommerce.
The question is: How can i make a role for every user to see only his orders and not orders from other customers?
Thanks

Comment: In WooCommerce, a user cannot see other user's orders

Comment: They can't should be, even they try using direct ID. Except you are an admin and access it from wp-admin.